# Using django-channels with django-rest-framework in the creation of mobile application

Tags: ios, django, django-rest-framework, django-channels, django-oscar

I already have a project writen in Django and I am able to use the django rest framework well with it. This project is actually based on django-oscar and I implemented some other features. I am now in the middle of working with the mobile version of this application and I am in need of realtime server updates like Sockets and I am aware of djnago channels. My question now is this, Is it possible to link django-rest framework with django-channels because if for example a user makes a purchase on the mobile app, the number of available products should decrease in real-time or if a user adds a product to cart the user should be a able to get an increased number of items immediately reflected witha notification badge and I feel this can be achieved by django channels. So how can I relate the rest API to django channels

Comment: Nothing technical, but I think from a business perspective (depending on the items you might be selling this would change), it's usually that items may get added to cart, but not go all the way to checkout. So, in that case, it will be advisable to not directly affect product availability based on that.

Comment: you may find https://github.com/hishnash/djangochannelsrestframework useful as this will help you share some of your existing DRF serializers etc over the WebSocket connection.  [disclamer I am the author of this package]

Comment: Awesome package would definitely go in depth of it. Hopefully you would keep building on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
URLRouter([
    url(r"^longpoll/$", LongPollConsumer),
    url(r"^notifications/(?P<stream>\w+)/$", LongPollConsumer),
    url(r"", AsgiHandler),
])
```

If a http argument is not provided, it will default to the Django view system’s ASGI interface, channels.http.AsgiHandler, which means that for most projects that aren’t doing custom long-poll HTTP handling, you can simply not specify a http option and leave it to work the “normal” Django way.

If you want to split HTTP handling between long-poll handlers and Django views, use a URLRouter with channels.http.AsgiHandler specified as the last entry with a match-everything pattern.

The content above is from  https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/routing.html#protocoltyperouter